# wordpress 3.5.1 Featured Image not showing up...?

Tags: wordpress

This is what inside my function.php

`<?php
    if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' )){
       add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    }`

`if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' )){
       add_image_size('featured', 400, 340, true);
       add_image_size('post-thumb', 100, 140, true);
     }
?>`

This is what inside my index.php

`<?php the_post_thumbnail('post-thumb'); ?>`

1. Featured Image in `Screen Options` enabled.
2. Featured Image metabox displaying on `Edit Post`
3. Featured Image is set.

the problem is the thumbnail not showing in index.php(homepage). Am I missing something? Big thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Put below code just above:  the_content();

```
<?php
   if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
   the_post_thumbnail('post-thumb');
   }
 ?>
```

See it for more information: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail and https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39798/thumbnail-cropping-with-add-image-size

Comment: I've done this already but didn't work. I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Replace nonworking code

```
add_theme_support(‘post-thumbnails’);
```

with working variant:

```
add_theme_support( ‘post-thumbnails’, array( ‘post’, ‘page’, ‘player’ ) );
```